# Can a Sequential Keras-model get multidimensional input (such as an image) that is not flattened (i.e. input shape is MxN pixels per image)?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, typeerror

I'm a Keras beginner, and am trying to build the simplest possible autoencoder. It consists of three layers: an input layer, an encoded representation layer, and an output layer. My data (training and validation images) are an ndarray where each image is 214x214x3 (pixels x pixels x RGB channels). I thought I could just use the input shape of the images in the Input layer, but somehow I keep encountering errors.

I tried flattening the data, and that works just fine. I can of course just do that, and reshape the output, but I'm curious why this doesn't work.

```py
# Shape and size of single image
input_shape = x_tr.shape[1:] # --> (214, 214, 3)
input_size = x_tr[0].size

# Size of encoded representation
encoding_dim = 32
compression_factor = float(input_size / encoding_dim)

# Build model
autoencoder = Sequential()
autoencoder.add(Dense(encoding_dim, input_shape=input_shape, 
    activation='relu'))
autoencoder.add(Dense(input_shape, activation='softmax'))

input_img = Input(shape=(input_shape,))
encoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[0]
encoder = Model(input_img, encoder_layer(input_img))

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='mean_squared_error')
autoencoder.fit(x_tr, x_tr,
                epochs=50,
                batch_size=32,
                shuffle=True,
                verbose=1,
                validation_data=(x_va, x_va),
                callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='/tmp/autoencoder2')])
```

I get this error:

```sh
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

I gather that it's not expecting the input shape to look like that, but am unsure of how to fix it to accept input in the shape of 214x214x3 rather than a vector of length 137388.

Comment: Could you provide the location of the error ?

Comment: also, it seems like **input_shape** is already a tuple, so no need to do **(input_shape,)** in the **Input**

Comment: Yes of course, quite negligent of me. It's actually this line:     autoencoder.add(Dense(input_shape, activation='softmax'))

Comment: Yes, good catch on the Input line. The problem below persists though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dense** Takes an integer as an input (the number of neurons), you provided a tuple
Try:

```py
output_dim = 214 * 214 * 3
autoencoder.add(Dense(output_dim, activation='softmax'))
```

You need to flatten your inputs/outputs, the fully connected Dense layer expects a 1-dimension input/output.

Comment: So as I understand, the input can be 'unflattened', but the output will be a vector, so it's more efficient to work with flattened input and output. Thanks!